# Select item value with radio buttons

Tags: javascript

```js
function cittaBox() {
    var selezione = Document.getElementById("selector");
    var selezioneTxt = selezione.options[selezione.selectedIndex].text;
    Document.getElementById("txtBox").value=selezioneTxt;}
```

```html
<SELECT NAME="citta" id="selector" onchange="cittaBox()">
                  <OPTION value="Roma">   Roma   </OPTION>
                  <OPTION value="Milano">   Milano   </OPTION>
                  <OPTION value="Torino">   Torino </OPTION>
                  <OPTION value="Napoli">   Napoli  </OPTION>
                  <OPTION value="Bari">   Bari    </OPTION>
                  <OPTION value="Taranto">   Taranto    </OPTION>
                  <OPTION value="Lecce">   Lecce    </OPTION>
               </SELECT>
               </P>
               <P align= "center" id="selezione0">
                  <INPUT type="text" name="citta" size="40" id="txtBox">
                </P>
```

any idea on why it doesn't work?

Comment: JS is case-sensitive. Use `document` **not** `Document`.

Comment: And if you look into your browser's console you'll see why it doesn't work: the error message will let you know what went wrong where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javascript is a case sensitive Use **document** instead of Document other than that nothing problem with your code

```
function cittaBox() {

    var selezione = document.getElementById("selector");
    var selezioneTxt = selezione.options[selezione.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("txtBox").value=selezioneTxt;
}
```

i hope you get answer..

Answer (score 0):

replace Document.getElementById by document.getElementById

Answer (score 0):

Your code looking good. But you have only one mistake. Change Document`to`document`. Lowercase. Then it work.

```js
function cittaBox() {
  console.log(1)
    var selezione = document.getElementById("selector");
    var selezioneTxt = selezione.options[selezione.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("txtBox").value=selezioneTxt;
}
```

```html
<SELECT NAME="citta" id="selector" onchange="cittaBox()">
                  <OPTION value="Roma">   Roma   </OPTION>
                  <OPTION value="Milano">   Milano   </OPTION>
                  <OPTION value="Torino">   Torino </OPTION>
                  <OPTION value="Napoli">   Napoli  </OPTION>
                  <OPTION value="Bari">   Bari    </OPTION>
                  <OPTION value="Taranto">   Taranto    </OPTION>
                  <OPTION value="Lecce">   Lecce    </OPTION>
               </SELECT>
               </P>
               <P align= "center" id="selezione0">
                  <INPUT type="text" name="citta" size="40" id="txtBox">
                </P>
```